# How to get data from specific event target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list.js

I'm trying to extract the name of a street using a click event in my `list` the entire process of getting the address data is working perfectly using `AJAX` successful callback I added a successful customer dialog containing the street information he clicked on.

But at the time of the street show in the successful dialogue I wanted to just get the street name and transport it to a input that will be `hidden` i wish to use the name of that street so that in the future when the client clicks a button copy the address for the form a `AJAX` that can do a search in my API using the name of this street so that in return of this action return an extended version of that address to my form.

But I can not think or find anything on how to extract just the street name that the client clicked on the list only thing that he can return to me is the original elements generated at the beginning of the list grouping using a route from my API that contains all the registered addresses

I already tried to get the data via the class of the generated elements, but none results.. i am have thought of trying to add an ID to the addresses that were clicked but I could not find anything in the jQuery documentation that could help me.

My elements.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Setup Modal
    $('#openSearchAddress').click(function() { 
        // Start Modal
        $('#modalSearchAddress')
           .modal('show')
        ;
    });

    $('#sendSearchAddress').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: "https://****-api.herokuapp.com/api/itapetininga-street-last-three-searcheds?access_token=7Z****",
            success: function (finalData) {
                // Running test
                console.log(finalData);

                if (finalData) {
                    // var dd = JSON.parse(result);
                    // addressStreet(finalData[0].addressStreet)
                    // name: finalData[0].addressStreet

                    // Print Results
                    var options = {
                        valueNames: ['addressStreet', 'neighborhoodStreet']
                    };

                    // Example One
                    var values = finalData.map(function(finalDatum) {
                        return {
                            addressStreet: finalDatum.addressStreet,
                            neighborhoodStreet: finalDatum.neighborhoodStreet,
                        };
                    });

                    var userList = new List('users', options, values);

                    // Start Selected Address With Event Delegation
                    $("#target_ul").on("click", "li", function(event) {
                        // Prevent Redirect In Click
                        event.preventDefault();

                        // Load Options For Notification
                        var placementFrom = "top";
                        var placementAlign = "center";
                        var colorName = "bg-light-green";

                        // Set Options For Notification
                        showNotification(colorName, null, placementFrom, placementAlign);

                        // Start New Notification
                        function showNotification(colorName, text, placementFrom, placementAlign, animateEnter, animateExit) {
                            if (colorName === null || colorName === '') { colorName = 'bg-black'; }
                            if (text === null || text === '') { text = 'Endereço que você selecionou é '; }
                            if (animateEnter === null || animateEnter === '') { animateEnter = 'animated fadeInDown'; }
                            if (animateExit === null || animateExit === '') { animateExit = 'animated fadeOutUp'; }
                            var allowDismiss = true;
                            // Start Modern Structure For Notification
                            $.notify({
                                message: text
                            }, {
                                type: colorName,
                                allow_dismiss: allowDismiss,
                                newest_on_top: true,
                                timer: 1000,
                                placement: {
                                    from: placementFrom,
                                    align: placementAlign
                                },
                                animate: {
                                    enter: animateEnter,
                                    exit: animateExit
                                },
                                template: '<div data-notify="container" class="bootstrap-notify-container alert alert-dismissible {0} ' + (allowDismiss ? "p-r-35" : "") + '" role="alert">' +
                                    '<button type="button" aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-notify="dismiss">×</button>' +
                                    '<span data-notify="icon"></span> ' +
                                    '<span data-notify="title">{1}</span> ' +
                                    '<span data-notify="message">{2}</span>' +
                                    '<div class="progress" data-notify="progressbar">' +
                                    '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-{0}" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"></div>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                    '<div id="selectedAddress"></div>' +
                                    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="alert-link" id="selectedSearchAddress" hidden></a>' +
                                    '<a href="{3}" target="{4}" data-notify="url"></a>' +
                                    '</div>'
                                }
                            );
                        }

                        // Add Selected Address In Notification
                        var selectedAddress = $( this ).text();

                        console.log('Selected address is: ', selectedAddress);

                        if (event.target && event.target.nodeName === 'LI') {
                            let item = event.target;

                            $("#selectedAddress").html(item.innerHTML);
                        }

                        // Prepare Input Hidden For Import Data To Form

                        // Add Informations About Selected Address
                        $('#selectedSearchAddress').text(selectedAddress);
                    });

                    // Print Variable Contain Native Data From All Street In List
                    console.log(values);
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
```

My list in EJS template

```
<div id="modalSearchAddress" class="ui small modal" style="margin-bottom: 53px !important;margin-top: 60px !important;margin-left: auto !important;margin-right: auto !important;">
    <div class="content" style="padding: 0rem !important;">
        <div class="row" style="margin-left: -30px !important; margin-right: -30px !important;">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div id="users">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 0px !important;">
                            <div class="header bg-indigo">
                                <h2 class="align-center">
                                    Pesquisar Endereço
                                    <small>Aqui você pode encontrar qualquer endereço cadastrado em seu catálogo...</small>
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div style="background: #eeeeee; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 3px;">
                            <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 0px !important;">
                                <div class="form-line">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control search align-center" id="nameSearchAddress" placeholder="Pesquise por endereços cadastrado em seu catálogo...">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12" >
                        <ul class="list list-search-address" id="target_ul">
                            <li>
                                <h3 class="addressStreet">Test</h3>
                                <p class="neighborhoodStreet">Test</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="Justified button group">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn bg-indigo waves-effect sort" role="button" data-sort="name">CLASSIFICAR POR NOME</a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn bg-indigo waves-effect" role="button" id="sendSearchAddress">ATUALIZAR</a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn bg-indigo waves-effect" role="button">COPIAR PARA FORMULARIO</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much for helping me, I'm trying to do this for two long days...
**Success Data (finalData) returned by Ajax**

```
[{
    "addressStreet": "Rua Baltazar Lorenzetto",
    "neighborhoodStreet": "Jardim Brasil",
    "latStreet": "Esperando latitude",
    "lngStreet": "Esperando longitude",
    "postalCodeStreet": "18214-490",
    "cityStreet": "Itapetininga",
    "stateStreet": "São Paulo",
    "id": "5a90b6b5c59ccc00148766b1"
}, {
    "addressStreet": "Rua Doutor Campos Sales",
    "neighborhoodStreet": "Centro",
    "latStreet": "-23.588984",
    "lngStreet": "-48.050931",
    "postalCodeStreet": "Esperando código postal",
    "cityStreet": "Itapetininda",
    "stateStreet": "São Paulo",
    "id": "5a94332d03d2a4001407a07c"
}, {
    "addressStreet": "Rua José de Almeida Carvalho",
    "neighborhoodStreet": "Centro",
    "latStreet": "-23.5785848",
    "lngStreet": "-48.027667",
    "postalCodeStreet": "18200-354",
    "cityStreet": "Itapetininga",
    "stateStreet": "São Paulo",
    "id": "5a948a0f03d2a4001407a07d"
}, {
    "addressStreet": "Esperando endereço...",
    "neighborhoodStreet": "Esperando bairro...",
    "latStreet": "Esperando latitude",
    "lngStreet": "Esperando longitude",
    "postalCodeStreet": "Esperando código postal",
    "cityStreet": "Esperando cidade",
    "stateStreet": "Esperando estado",
    "id": "5a9eb0e4a086fb0014b65b45",
    "term": "Rua Ba"
}, {
    "addressStreet": "Esperando endereço...",
    "neighborhoodStreet": "Esperando bairro...",
    "latStreet": "Esperando latitude",
    "lngStreet": "Esperando longitude",
    "postalCodeStreet": "Esperando código postal",
    "cityStreet": "Esperando cidade",
    "stateStreet": "Esperando estado",
    "id": "5a9eb0e5a086fb0014b65b46",
    "term": "Rua Bal"
}, {
    "addressStreet": "Esperando endereço...",
    "neighborhoodStreet": "Esperando bairro...",
    "latStreet": "Esperando latitude",
    "lngStreet": "Esperando longitude",
    "postalCodeStreet": "Esperando código postal",
    "cityStreet": "Esperando cidade",
    "stateStreet": "Esperando estado",
    "id": "5a9eb0e7a086fb0014b65b47",
    "term": "Rua Balta"
}, {
    "addressStreet": "Esperando endereço...",
    "neighborhoodStreet": "Esperando bairro...",
    "latStreet": "Esperando latitude",
    "lngStreet": "Esperando longitude",
    "postalCodeStreet": "Esperando código postal",
    "cityStreet": "Esperando cidade",
    "stateStreet": "Esperando estado",
    "id": "5a9eb135a086fb0014b65b4b"
}, {
    "addressStreet": "Esperando endereço...",
    "neighborhoodStreet": "Esperando bairro...",
    "latStreet": "Esperando latitude",
    "lngStreet": "Esperando longitude",
    "postalCodeStreet": "Esperando código postal",
    "cityStreet": "Esperando cidade",
    "stateStreet": "Esperando estado",
    "id": "5a9eb136a086fb0014b65b4c"
}, {
    "addressStreet": "Esperando endereço...",
    "neighborhoodStreet": "Esperando bairro...",
    "latStreet": "Esperando latitude",
    "lngStreet": "Esperando longitude",
    "postalCodeStreet": "Esperando código postal",
    "cityStreet": "Esperando cidade",
    "stateStreet": "Esperando estado",
    "id": "5a9eb136a086fb0014b65b4d"
}, {
    "addressStreet": "Esperando endereço...",
    "neighborhoodStreet": "Esperando bairro...",
    "latStreet": "Esperando latitude",
    "lngStreet": "Esperando longitude",
    "postalCodeStreet": "Esperando código postal",
    "cityStreet": "Esperando cidade",
    "stateStreet": "Esperando estado",
    "id": "5a9eb15aa086fb0014b65b50"
}]
```

Response in my console after click in List

```
elements.js:85 (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
elements.js:189 (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
elements.js:174 Selected address is:  
            Rua Baltazar Lorenzetto
             Jardim Brasil
```

Comment: can you please log the `finaldata` object the API returns? and also update the question accordingly with the data.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal Sorry, I'm adding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To someone who was in the same doubt as I, analyzing more about what our friend @AkshayKhandelwal told me. I was trying to request information that is no longer the same from the beginning of the Api Get. By getting a specific target, we lose access to our raw JSON access, returned at the beginning of the function. By solution, I decided to choose to build a controller using ANGULAR JS, utilizing this method obtaining our event becomes much more manipulative and scaleable.

```
// Query Address In Catalog
$('#openSearchAddress').click(function() { 
    // Start Modal
    $('#modalSearchAddress')
       .modal('show')
    ;
});
```

> The call of modal remains the same

```
angular.module('YourModuleName', [You can extend it using other libraries])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "Your API Link"
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        // Print JSON in console
        // $scope.myWelcome = response.data;

        $scope.iconType = 'fa fa-circle-o';

        $scope.data = {
            showDelete: false
        };

        $scope.edit = function (item) {
            alert('Edit Item: ' + item.addressStreet);
        };

        $scope.clicker = function (item) {
            alert('Clicked chevron: ' + item.addressStreet)
        };
        $scope.share = function (item) {
            alert('Share Item: ' + item.addressStreet);
        };

        $scope.moveItem = function (item, fromIndex, toIndex) {
            $scope.items.splice(fromIndex, 1);
            $scope.items.splice(toIndex, 0, item);
        };

        $scope.onItemDelete = function (item) {
            $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
        };

        $scope.circleClicked = function (item) {
            alert('You selected Item: ' + item.addressStreet);
        }

        // Set Scope Contains Response Data
        $scope.items = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
    });
});
```

I had to restore our structure on the front end, you can add pagination, query, filters, highlights, whatever you want here. The style sheet you can customize to your liking :]

```
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="list-search-address">
                    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter : search" item="item" href="#/item/{{item.id}}" style="display: block; background-color: #eee; padding: 10px; box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;">
                        <h3 style="font-size: 16px; margin: 0 0 0.3rem; font-weight: normal; font-weight: bold;">
                            <i ng-class="iconType" ng-mousedown="iconType='fa fa-check-circle-o'" ng-mouseup="iconType='fa fa-circle-o'" ng-click="circleClicked(item)"></i>{{ item.addressStreet }}</h3>
                        <p>{{ item.neighborhoodStreet }}</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Thanks for enlightening my ideas xD

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
              $("#target_ul").on("click", "li", function(event) {
                    var self = $(this);         // Storing the reference of the element
                    ...................... // Your code as is
                    ......................
                    // Add Selected Address In Notification
                    var selectedAddress = $( self ).text();       // Using the reference of the stored element
                    ....................... // Your code as is
                    .......................
```

Comment: What actually happening here is that when you have a function inside the event handler, the function's `this` keyword points to the `window` and not the element that you expect. hence the issue

Comment: And BTW you should accept if the answer is correct.

Comment: Why? I already have access to the complete result What I desire is to separate the address of the neighborhood in the result, I wish to transport only the address for an input instead of the street and neighborhood together, understood?

Comment: @smachs I said earlier that the result that you are targetting by using the `this` keyword is no more the same result. You lost access to it as it now points to `window`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yessss, you think I'll have to redo my event target?

Comment: in your show notification function, you need to either pass a reference of `this` or as in the answer assign `this` to some variable and use it inside show notification

Comment: The first option works here as you are calling show notification right from within the valid scope.

Comment: when I call `this` as a variable the return showed me only html elements of the list containing the clicked value https://i.imgur.com/OtQVmvj.png would it be possible if on the click on my list it returns the json value from the complete list of addresses?